# How to display the AJAX response in input field and pass that value to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am getting Id value from my AJAX and I am also able to display it. I set the Id value input text in the AJAX and displaying it on HTML like this `<input value="4864" id="compare_id" type="hidden">` Now I have to pass that value to PHP to get the result from database.
Is there any idea how to do it?

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  arr = [];
  $("[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "includes/compare_process.php", // 
      data: 'users=' + arr,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(msg) {
        $("#pics_name,#pics_Id").empty();
        $.each(msg, function() {
          $("#pics_Id").append("<input type=hidden value=" + this.Id + " id=compare_id name=compare_id>");
          //alert(msg.id);
        });

      },
      error: function() {
        alert("failure");
      }
    });
  });
});


//tried AJAX
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search-button').click(function(){
            $.ajax( {
                type: "GET",
                url: 'includes/compare_process.php?key=compare_details',
                data: $('#search-form').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    //$('#response').html(response);
                    alert(response);
                }
            } );
        });
    });
```

**PHP**

```
<div class="bg-popup" style="display: none;" id="open_compare_popup">
//popup code here
    <?php 
     $val2=htmlentities($_GET['compare_id']);
     echo $val2;
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `request` WHERE Id IN($val2)";
     ?>
//end popup code here
```

This output I am getting from AJAX

```
<form action="#" method="get" id="search-form">
<span id="pics_Id">
<input value="4869" id="compare_id" name="compare_id" type="hidden">//output
<input value="4884" id="compare_id" name="compare_id" type="hidden">//output
<input value="5010" id="compare_id" name="compare_id" type="hidden">//output
</span>
<button class="action action--button action--compare" type="button" id="search-button" name="search-button"><span class="action__text">Compare</span></button>
</form>
```

I have to pass the input value to PHP after clicking on a button.

Comment: Why dont you put second AJAX in the success block of the first one? If you really want get method, then type:'GET", data: 'compare_id='+msg.Id

Comment: Is it possible that your form is being submitted because you have a button inside it? Unless you specify type="button" in some browsers that button might submit the form

Comment: I don't get what you mean.Add another field after the ajax and then do something? You also add a bunch of duplicated html ids.

Comment: Actually it seems like you may not need to use a form field at all. If you are not collecting any data from the user maybe you can just try removing the form tag altogether and put your onClick action on the button

Comment: Actually I am getting Id from database and that id i have to pass to the php. I just need idea how can I do this. What my logic is I set that Id in input field . Is there any other option??

Comment: @vladatr, hoe can I use the second Ajax because I have to set the click event after getting the Id

Comment: @NarendraVerma if I understand you good, the first ajax call gets you the ID. There is no need for another click. SUCCESS part of your first ajax call will happen when you get the ID, and that will be the trigger to call second ajax.

Comment: @vladatr , Please can you share the example of it ?

Comment: Why would you need a _second_ request in the first place? You are only populating the form with hidden input fields, so the user is not supposed to change anything about them, right? Well then why are you sending them on this needless round-trip via the client in the first place? You _had_ the values available server-side when you made your first AJAX request. So do whatever needs to be done on the server with those values _“in”_ this first AJAX request ...

Comment: @CBroe, What I am doing is, I am getting Id from database in first AJAX and I have to display that Id on input fields so that any user clicked on the button then that Id values pass to PHP function.

Comment: @CBroe, Do you have any other logic to solve this issue?

Comment: _“and I have to display that Id on input fields”_ - well _hidden_ input fields don’t display much to the user ... So what is it that you actually want to achieve here? Show the user some kind of confirmation, “Delete Records with IDs 3, 7 and 45?” or sth. like that?

Comment: Is your main problem maybe just that the click event handler for `#search-button` doesn’t work? Well that is because that element does not exists at the time you tried to select it ... _because_ you only insert it after your first AJAX request. The easy solution for _that_ problem is called _event delegation_.

Comment: @CBroe, Yes, I don't want to show the input box to the user that's the reason I used hidden. I just want user to click on button and in the background that Id will pass to PHP

Comment: But why does this need a second request then? If you don’t even show the ids to me - then why are you not doing whatever needs to be done with those values directly in your _first_ AJAX request?

Comment: In the first comment @vladatr, suggested me to use second AJAX. That why I am trying to use second.